# How to make a member of a class an object in perl

Tags: perl, oop

Hello basically it is a question of OO programming in perl. I want to have two objects A and B, and A contains a member variable which of type B. I did  some tests but seems it doesn't work. Any idea?

## a.pm

```
package a;


sub new{
    my $self = {};
    my $b = shift;
    $self->{B} = $b;
    bless $self;
    return $self;
}

sub doa{
    my $self = shift;
    print "a\n";
    $self->{B}->dob;
}

1;
```

## b.pm

```
package b;

sub new {
    my $self = {};
    bless $self;
    return $self;
}

sub dob{
    my $self = shift;
    print "b\n";
} 



1;
```

## test.pl

```
use a;
use b;

my $b = b->new;
my $a = a->new($b);
$a->doa;
```

When I ran this, it shows:

```
a
Can't locate object method "dob" via package "a" at a.pm line 16.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot about the method's first parameter. The first parameter of a method is always the invocant.

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $b) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    $self->{B} = $b;
    return bless($self, $class);
}
```

---

I usually `bless` first, though

```
sub new {
    my ($class, ...) = @_;
    my $self = bless({}, $class);
    $self->{attribute} = ...;
    return $self;
}
```

because it's more consistent with the constructor of a derived class.

```
sub new {
    my ($class, ...) = @_;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new(...);
    $self->{attribute} = ...;
    return $self;
}
```

Comment: Added a style note to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to make Perl OO easier by using something like [Moose](http://p3rl.org/Moose) or its lighter cousin [Moo](http://p3rl.org/Moo). Also you might like the (free) [Modern Perl Book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) to learn about the many new and exciting thing that more modern Perl has to offer!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package ClassA;

use Moo;

has 'b' => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => sub { shift->isa('ClassB') or die "Need a ClassB\n" },  # not necessary but handy
  required => 1,
);

sub doa {
    my $self = shift;
    print "a\n";
    $self->b->dob;
}

package ClassB;

use Moo;

sub dob {
  my $self = shift;
  print "b\n";
}

package main;

my $b = ClassB->new;
my $a = ClassA->new( b => $b );
$a->doa;
```

In fact, depending on what you want, perhaps you even might want something like delegation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package ClassA;

use Moo;

has 'b' => (
  is => 'ro',
  isa => sub { shift->isa('ClassB') or die "Need a ClassB\n" },  # not necessary but handy
  required => 1,
  handles => ['dob'],
);

sub doa {
    my $self = shift;
    print "a\n";
}

package ClassB;

use Moo;

sub dob {
  my $self = shift;
  print "b\n";
}

package main;

my $b = ClassB->new;
my $a = ClassA->new( b => $b );
$a->doa;
$a->dob;
```

Comment: Couldn't you change the "isa" to `isa => 'ClassB',`?

Comment: If you are using Moose, but not in Moo. Its one of the few differences, and honestly I usually omit the `isa` check when using Moo.

Answer (score 2):

You are not [blessing your objects](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) properly. Try this:

A:

```
sub new {                                                                                                                                                                                               
    my $class = shift;                                                                                                                                                                                 
    my $b = shift;                                                                                                                                                                                     
    return bless { B => $b }, $class;                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

B:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {}, $class; 
}
```